# Json Object : Group by on 2nd level attribute

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've a big array of following type objects.

```
[{
    iD: "djfaj",
    compositeAttr: { "type": "book", val: "atlas", domain: "abc.com" },
    otherattr: 'val1'
}, {
    iD: "djfaj1",
    compositeAttr: { "type": "toy", val: "globe", domain: "xyz.com" },
    otherattr: 'val2'
}, {
    iD: "djfaj2",
    compositeAttr: { "type": "toy", val: "car", domain: "xyz.com" },
    otherattr: 'val3'
}
//... some more objects
]
```

I want o/p as follows:

```
[{
    "xyz.com": [{
        iD: "djfaj1",
        compositeAttr: { "type": "toy", val: "globe", domain: "xyz.com" },
        otherattr: 'val2'
    }, {
        iD: "djfaj2",
        compositeAttr: { "type": "toy", val: "car", domain: "xyz.com" },
        otherattr: 'val3'
    }]
}, {
    "abc.com": [{
        iD: "djfaj",
        compositeAttr: { "type": "book", val: "atlas", domain: "abc.com" },
        otherattr: 'val1'
    }]
}]
```

How would I do this with lodash or similar library?
Having this change will help a lot to improve the performance.

Comment: is the mixed up `"djfaj'` intended?

Comment: `_.groupBy(array, function(elt) { return elt.compositeAttr.domain; })`

Comment: Nope, that's a dummay data,  i've replaced the actual iD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using lodash you could try something like this

```
 var arr = [{iD: "djfaj", compositeAttr: {"type": "book", val: "atlas", domain: "abc.com"}, otherattr: 'val1'}, {iD: "djfaj1", compositeAttr: {"type": "toy", val: "globe", domain: "xyz.com"}, otherattr: 'val2'}, {iD: "djfaj2", compositeAttr: {"type": "toy", val: "car", domain: "xyz.com"}, otherattr: 'val3'}];

 var result = _(arr).groupBy('compositeAttr.domain').map(function(v, k) {
     var obj = {};
     obj[k] = v;
     return obj;
 }).value();

 console.log(result);
```

[lodash demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/XE1bsigLEqUq1w6U8TS6?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating and an object for collecting.

```js
var obj = [{ iD: 'djfaj', compositeAttr: { type: 'book', val: 'atlas', domain: 'abc.com' }, otherattr: 'val1' }, { iD: 'djfaj1', compositeAttr: { type: 'toy', val: 'globe', domain: 'xyz.com' }, otherattr: 'val2' }, { iD: ' djfaj2', compositeAttr: { type: 'toy', val: 'car', domain: 'xyz.com' }, otherattr: 'val3' }],
    grouped = {},
    result = [];

obj.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.compositeAttr.domain] = grouped[a.compositeAttr.domain] || [];
    grouped[a.compositeAttr.domain].push(a);
});

Object.keys(grouped).forEach(function (k) {
    var o= {};
    o[k] = grouped[k];
    result.push(o);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Good and clean answer, Unfortunately not the output format asked by Ganesh. Anyway, this should be marked as answer because more efficient and elegant